# Languages supported by CP1242

Tags: windows, character-encoding, windows-1252

What is an official site from where I can get a list of Languages supported by CP1242

Comment: The question is constructive and should not have been closed. Windows-1252 is now even endorsed by the W3C as the de facto replacement for ISO 8859-1 (at least as relates to HTML), so the question is also practically relevant, and constructive (though perhaps not perfect) answers have been given.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows XP, the following languages have a default ANSI code page of 1252 (for at least one country):

- af = Afrikaans
- arn =
- ca = Catalan
- cy = Welsh
- da = Danish
- de = German
- en = English
- es = Spanish
- eu = Basque
- fi = Finnish
- fil =
- fo = Faeroese
- fr = French
- fy = Frisian
- ga = Irish
- gl = Galician
- id = Indonesian
- is = Icelandic
- it = Italian
- iu = Inuktitut
- iv =
- lb =
- moh =
- ms = Malay
- nb =
- nl = Dutch
- nn =
- ns =
- pt = Portuguese
- qu = Quechua
- rm = Rhaeto-Romance
- se =
- sv = Swedish
- sw = Swahili
- tn = Setswana
- xh = Xhosa
- zu = Zulu

Comment: So in other words: af, arn, ca, cy, da, de, en, es, eu, fi, fil, fo, fr, fy, ga, gl, id, is, it, iu, iv, lb, moh, ms, nb, nl, nn, ns, pt, qu, rm, se, sv, sw, tn, xh, zu after eliminating the country dialects. How would one convert those to actual names?

Comment: Using [ISO 639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) I translated them to: Afrikaans, Catalan; Valencian, Welsh, Danish, German, English, Spanish; Castilian, Basque, Finnish, Faroese, French, Western Frisian, Irish, Galician, Indonesian, Icelandic, Italian, Inuktitut, Luxembourgish, Letzeburgesch, Malay, Norwegian Bokmål, Dutch, Norwegian Nynorsk, Portuguese, Quechua, Romansh, Northern Sami, Swedish, Swahili, Tswana, Xhosa, Zulu but I missed some.

Answer (score 0):

According to [these guys](http://www.science.co.il/language/Character-Code.asp?s=1252) and the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset-lang.html):

Afrikaans, Albanian, Basque, Catalan, Danish, Dutch, English, Faroese, Finnish, French, Galician, German, Icelandic, Indonesian, Irish, Italian, Norwegian, Portuguese, Scottish, Spanish, Swedish.